# Spring MVC - No mapping found for request URI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I get some problem using spring MVC
Here is my web.xml config

```
<!-- config spring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml,
                /WEB-INF/classes/xfire-servlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/classes/mvc-servlet.xml,
                classpath:org/codehaus/xfire/spring/xfire.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
   <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
 <listener> 
   <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- spring mvc -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My controller is following

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/searchCase.do")
public class SearchCaseController {

      public String getCaseDetailInfo() {
           return "forward:caseDetail";
      }

}
```

and my mvc config is

```
<!--auto scan annotation -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.thunisoft.shxt.webservice.model.searchCase.logic" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/case" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Then I request through the url:http://{address:port}/{application-name}/searchCase.do,But it can't find the controller to resolve my request with

```
 No handler found in getLastModified
 DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc' processing request for [/{application-name}/searchCase.do]
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/{application-name}/searchCase.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc'
 Successfully completed request
```

My spring MVC version is 2.5.6 
I'm waiting for your questions to help me solve this problem,thank you!

Comment: what is the name of your config xml file?

Comment: The config of xml file's name is mvc.xml

Comment: make it springMVC-servlet.xml, then try.

Comment: I have do it,but it didn't work!I seems that the framework can find the config xml!

Comment: the base package used in component scan matches with the controller's package?

Comment: Yes,My controller is in the base package, bur it seems that the controller hasn't been scaned

Comment: You also need to annotate the method `getCaseDetailInfo`. In my project I get the same error if I don't do it so. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: There is no `@RequestMapping` on your method, so it won't be mapped. Also you are loading your `mvc-servlet.xml` twice. Don't do things like that (your `ContextLoaderListener` shouldn't load that file). You also seem to lack `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Please change the controller URL pattern as I mentioned below

.do will gets appended automatically to all controller request mapping since you configured in web.xml

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/searchCase")
public class SearchCaseController {

      public String getCaseDetailInfo() {
           return "forward:caseDetail";
      }

}
```

JSP Code :

```
<a href="/searchCase.do">Click</a>
```

Comment: I guess you mean        <a href="/{application-name}/searchCase.do">Click</a>        I do it following you advice,but I didn't work ether,I plus an `init()` method in my controller to see whether it has been found and initialize,and the `init()` invoked while the server start up,I can't find,where is the problem!

Comment: What error actually you have ?.Please post the error.

Comment: Hi,here is the error `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/{application-name}/searchCase.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc'`

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">

Comment: Please use above code snippet in your dispatcher servlet and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a method level annotation like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/searchCase")
public class SearchCaseController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCaseDetailInfo() {
        return "forward:caseDetail";
    }

}
```

Like it's described in the docs: [Mapping Requests With @RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

> **17.3.2 Mapping Requests With @RequestMapping**
>
> You use the `@RequestMapping` annotation to map URLs such as
>   `/appointments` onto an entire class or a particular handler method.
>   Typically the class-level annotation maps a specific request path (or
>   path pattern) onto a form controller, with additional method-level
>   annotations narrowing the primary mapping for a specific HTTP method
>   request method ("GET", "POST", etc.) or an HTTP request parameter
>   condition.

Answer (score 0):

What people are suggesting in the comments is what the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) describe

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your
>   web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope.

However, by using the config

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>namespace</param-name>
    <param-value>mvc</param-value>
</init-param>
```

you have overriden this, so the DispatherServlet file will look at the following location

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION_PREFIX + getNamespace() + DEFAULT_CONFIG_LOCATION_SUFFIX
```

so in your example, it will be

```
/WEB-INF/mvc.xml
```

I see per your comment that you originally had the proper name (corresponding to your config). So its either that you haven't placed it under *WEB-INF*, or your issues are elsewhere.

This being said, do consider alternative configuration (more explicit in my opinion), based on `contextConfigLocation` param, e.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Firstly,thanks for your answer,and I do it following you advice,but I haver't solve it,and I have edit my `web.xml`,please help me to have a look whether it has some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I setup your project on my computer. First i run the project with ***maven-jetty-plugin***. Then No mapping found error occured. After lots of changes finally i tried ***maven-tomcat7-plugin*** then it worked.

Add tomcat plugin to your pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then start the server `mvn tomcat7:run`

Your Controller mapping should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchCase", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After trying out everything I found on stack overflow to no avail, I realised I had my controller in folder `src/main/resources/com/controllers`, where `com.controllers` was meant to be a package.

Creating another source folder `src/main/java` and moving the `com/controllers` folder there did the trick. (It detected the `com/controller` folder as a package whereas in `src/main/resources` it was treated as an ordinary directory.)

Comment: Also, don't forget to add <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> to your servlet xml file, otherwise it won't detect the controller.